# How do I stop an existing open shift Port Forward

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

With oc, I can portward a pod in open shift to get local access.

```
oc get pods
oc port-forward MY-POD-NAME  5555:5555
```

How do I stop it after I start it?

I've searched through

```
oc port-forward --help
```

I don't see a way to get a list of all "port-forwards" to try and get a unique name.

Error message when I try to start listening (note, my pod-name is different after redeployment)

> Unable to listen on port 5555: All listeners failed to create with the
>   following errors: Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4
>   127.0.0.1:5555: bind: address already in use, Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6: address [[::1]]:5555: missing port in
>   address error: Unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{5555
>   5555}]

URLs I have fished:

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/port_forwarding.html

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to stop `oc port-forward` by using `Ctrl-C` (confirmed [here](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-connecting-database-using-port-forwarding/)).

If the port is still stuck open, then you can use `sudo netstat -lnp` to find the PID keeping it open. For example:

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 5555
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      302867/oc           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5555                :::*                    LISTEN      302867/oc
```

Once you have the PID (which is the number here : 302867/oc), you can use `sudo kill -9 <PID>` to end the process, and that should free up that port.

Comment: So, just to follow up.  In my case CNTL-C gave me "control back" in my terminal window....AND if I tried to use the port, it failed.  So in that sense, CNTL-C worked.  BUT if I tried to then reissue the same "oc port-forward MY-POD-NAME  5555:5555" command....I get the exception "address already in use, Unable to create listener".  (do what open-shift team??) .   And that's when your netstat trick comes into play.  THANKS.